# How to auto delete generated sheets in excel using VBA ?

Tags: excel, vba

I used this code to delete list of sheets, but I see pop ups to DELETE or CANCEL.

```
Sub Del()

Dim A As Integer
A = Worksheets("RLI").Range("G2")
For i = 1 To A
Worksheets(CStr(i)).Delete
Next i
End Sub
```

I need to delete list of sheets without seeing the pop ups.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'delete the sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```